# What is the expected value of $\frac{1}{N+X}$ when $X$ is a poisson distributed random variabel?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, expected-value, random-functions

Assume that $X$ is a poisson distributed random variabel. That is, the probability of the event $X=i$ is $P(X=i)=\frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}$. Can anyone simplify the expression of $E[\frac{1}{N+X}]=\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{N+i} \frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}  $   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an integration trick :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[ \frac{1}{N+X} \right]&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{N+i} \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^N} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{N+i} \frac{\lambda^{N+i} }{i!}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^N} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\lambda \frac{t^{N+i-1} }{i!} dt\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^N}  \int_0^\lambda  t^{N-1} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{i} }{i!} dt\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^N}  \int_0^\lambda  t^{N-1} e^{-t} dt\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^N} (\Gamma(N,0)-\Gamma(N,\lambda))\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^N} (1-\Gamma(N,\lambda))
\end{align*}
Where $\Gamma(\cdot\,,\cdot)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) for which we have numerical values (especially if $N$ is an integer).